# What is the template or framework used to get the sidebar at beta.atmospherejs.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This site is responsive and really fast for the effects

What is the template or framework used to get the sidebar at beta.atmospherejs.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which framework can do it, but there're many good tuts for that similar effects by using css3.

You might have to check first one.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/18/perspective-page-view-navigation/

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/28/transitions-for-off-canvas-navigations/

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/

Comment: Exactly what I expected! Thanks